# How can I get the source code of a specific div on radio oncheck?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to get the source code of a div, so example if a div contains some tags I'd like to get them as they are in html format and update it on a textfield.

JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lindow/g1sp1ms3/2/

**HTML :**

```
<form>

    <label class="tp_box_1">
        <input type="radio" name="selected_layout" class="selected_layout" value="layout_1">
        <div class="box_1">
            <h3>box_one</h3>
            <p>1</p>
        </div>
    </label>

    <br><hr><br>

    <label class="tp_box_2">
        <input type="radio" name="selected_layout" class="selected_layout" value="layout_2">
        <div class="box_2">
            <h3>box_two</h3>
            <p>2</p>
        </div>
    </label>

    <textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
    <input id="submit_form" type="button" value="Send">
</form>
```

**JavaScript** :

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="selected_layout"]').change(function() {
     if(this.checked) {
         // get the specific div children of $this
         var selected_layout = $(this).find('.selected_layout');

         // get source code of what's inside the selected_layout
         /* example :
            <h3>box_two</h3>
            <p>2</p>
        and put it in someVariable.
         */

         // and put in into textarea (all this need to happens when a radio is changed with the source code of the checked div)
         var someVariable = ...
         $('textarea').val(someVariable);
     }
 });
```

How can I achieve this ? How can I get the source code inside a specific div ?

Comment: is [.innerHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) what you're looking for? (just [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) in jQuery) EDIT: not entirely, it doesn't contain the attributes of the element

Comment: @PatrickBarr Yes, but I thought innerHTML would get the string only and not the tags, guess I was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't want `selected_layout` to be equal to: `$(this).find('.selected_layout')` because `this` already points to that element. You want it to point to the next element that comes after it.

I think this is what you are looking for:

```js
$('input[type="radio"][name="selected_layout"]').change(function() {
     if(this.checked) {
         // get the index within the set of radio buttons for the radio button that was clicked
         var idx = $("[type=radio][class=selected_layout]").index(this);
         
         // Get the div structure that corresponds to the same index
         var test = $("[class^='box_']")[idx];

         // Now, just make that the value of the textarea
         $('textarea').val(test.innerHTML);
     }
 });
```

```css
textarea { width:100%; height:75px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

    <label class="tp_box_1">
        <input type="radio" name="selected_layout" id="sl1" class="selected_layout" value="layout_1">
        <div class="box_1">
            <h3>box_one</h3>
            <p>1</p>
        </div>
    </label>
    <label class="tp_box_2">
        <input type="radio" name="selected_layout" id="sl2" class="selected_layout" value="layout_2">
        <div class="box_2">
            <h3>box_two</h3>
            <p>2</p>
        </div>
    </label>

    <textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
    <input id="submit_form" type="button" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: Yes it's exactly what I want but is there a way to target the sibling by class instead using `nextElementSibling` ?

Comment: Well, there is, but since the class value will change depending on which radio button you click, why would you want that?

Comment: because, this was a schematisation and the real app has more div inside other div, so it won't be the next sibling, and `.selected_layout` doesn't change since it's a common class.

Comment: @Lindow Updated answer that doesn't rely on `nextElementSibling`, but rather correlates the index of the radio button within the group of radio buttons to the index of the `div` within the group of `div`s.

Answer (score 0):

Create `div` element with:

1. Template inside
2. `class` or `id` for identifying

Set inputs' value to desired template class/id, then on input change find the template element base on input's value and extract the innerHTML of it by using jQuery's `.html()` method. Then put this HTML as an new value of textarea using also the`.html()` method on textarea element.

HTML:

```
<div id="template1" style="display:none;">
    <h1>Hi!</h1>
</div>

<input type="radio" onchange="findTemplate(event)" value="template1" />
<textarea class="texta"></textarea>
```

jQuery:

```
var findTemplate = function(event) {
    var target       = $(event.target);
    var templateName = target.val();
    var template     = $("#"+templateName);
    var template     = template.html();
    var textarea     = $(".texta");
    textarea.html(template);
};
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rsvvx6da/1/